# Querying CSV file in S3 through Athena throws 403 Erroe Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a folder created in S3 called rawdata. There are Subfolders inside rawdata called masters, There are CSV files uploaded in rawdata and msters folders. I have created Tables in AWS Athena. While external tables get created from the AWS console. While I am querying the data I  am getting 403 access forbidden error. Here is the scenario :

**rawdata** is the top-level bucket.**

**rawdata**
        --->**masters**->s**ub Folder 1** -> File 1 -> (Athena External Table Created)-> but getting 403 error while auerying
                 ->**sub Folder 2** -> File 2 -> (Athena external Table Created)->but getting 403 error while querying
                 ->**sub Folder 3** -> File 3 -> (Athena external Table Created) but getting 403 error while querying.
       --> **File 4** (not inside any subfolder) -> Athena Table Created and query Works file at this level.

Any kind suggestions are welcome. I am starting off with AWS. 
Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: Possibly `you` may `not` have `permissions` to read the files under `folder1`,`folder2`,`folder3` by specific `deny`. While you may have permission to read the rest of files.

Comment: Can you post the IAM policy used for Athena and also confirm if the role used to upload files is different from the role used to query this data?